How to remove large if-else-if chain with the condition as String::startswith
How can I avoid this if-else chain? Moving this logic to switch case looks difficult, since this code flow does some sort of prefix matching and does something based on if the condition is true.
if (fullPathWithPrefix.startsWith("A")) {
    doA();
} else if (fullPathWithPrefix.startsWith("B")) {
    doB();
} else if (fullPathWithPrefix.startsWith("C")) {
    doC();
} else if (fullPathWithPrefix.startsWith("D")) { 
    doD();
} else if (fullPathWithPrefix.startsWith("E")) {
    doE();
}


This solution maybe cumbersome for your case. But if your target methods can be brought under one functional interface you can do something like this:
interface MyFunction {
    void doSomething();
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String fullPathWithPrefix = "Be careful";
        Map<String, MyFunction> prefixToTaskMap = Map.of(
                "A", Main::doA,
                "B", Main::doB,
                "C", Main::doC,
                "D", Main::doD,
                "E", Main::doE);

        for (Map.Entry<String, MyFunction> entry :prefixToTaskMap.entrySet()) {
            if (fullPathWithPrefix.startsWith(entry.getKey())) {
                entry.getValue().doSomething();
                // If one match found, no need to match others
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void doE() {
        System.out.println("E");
    }

    private static void doD() {
        System.out.println("D");
    }

    private static void doC() {
        System.out.println("C");
    }

    private static void doB() {
        System.out.println("B");
    }

    private static void doA() {
        System.out.println("A");
    }
}

I have created a new functional interface MyInterface. But your may match any of the standard functional interfaces in java.util.Function

Try using switch-case:
String fullPathWithPrefix = "your_path";
char prefix = fullPathWithPrefix.charAt(0);

switch (prefix) {
    case 'A' -> doA();
    case 'B' -> doB();
    case 'C' -> doC();
    case 'D' -> doD();
    case 'E' -> doE();
    default -> {
        // Default case
    }
}


( requires Java 14 or later [preview feature since Java12] )

In this case the param in switch is a expression to be evaluated against several prefixes, so how can switch case help here?

You could invoke doA()...doB() through function references. I would create a Map<String, Runnable> (because Runnable is a functional interface that takes no arguments). Assuming the current class is named Main, that might look something like
Map<String, Runnable> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("A", Main::doA);
map.put("B", Main::doB);
map.put("C", Main::doC);
map.put("D", Main::doD);
map.put("E", Main::doE);

Then to use it, you could iterate the map entry set like
for (Map.Entry<String, Runnable> me : map.entrySet()) {
    if (fullPathWithPrefix.startsWith(me.getKey())) {
        me.getValue().run();
    }
}

Or, if your prefixes are a consistent length, avoiding the loop with something like
String prefix = fullPathWithPrefix.substring(0, 1);
if (map.containsKey(prefix)) {
    map.get(prefix).run();
}


You could use reflection and call whatever required method based on the first string character determined from the fullPathWithPrefix string variable.
Here is just a simple example of how it could be done if all the methods are within the same class (read comments in code):
/* You will need to import:  java.lang.reflect.Method   */
        
String fullPathWithPrefix = "C:/Windows/OrWhatever";
        
// Get the first string character from fullPathWithPrefix and ensure uppercase:
String prefix = fullPathWithPrefix.trim().substring(0,1).toUpperCase();
        
/* Validate prefix string character. For methods doA(), doB(), doC(), 
   doD(), and doE() within the same class:        */
if (prefix.matches("[A-E]")) {
    // Call the required method based on the determined prefix string character:
    try {
        Method method = this.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("do" + prefix);
        method.invoke(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        // Do what you want with Exception(s)...Just don't leave it blank.
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No method for the Prefix: " + prefix);
}

